# Combine list of S4 objects into one S4 object

Tags: r, list, r-s4

I have a list of 10 S4 objects and each S4 object itself has multiple slots.
Is it possible to combine these S4 objects into one and append the slots?
[image: This is how my data looks]

So that predictions and all other elements have length 10?
I cant unlist these objects and don't really know what to do.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example for us to help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for instructions!

Comment: Yes, that's possible but the result won't necessarily be a valid object of class prediction. Why do you need this?